# Yii2. Не могу найти причину ошибки записи в базу данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii2

Не могу записать данные в таблицу, получаю ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `contact` (`id`) VALUES (DEFAULT)
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1364
    [2] => Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value
)
```

Контроллер:

```
$model = new ContactForm();
$model->id = 0;
$model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
$model->save(false);
```

Модель (правила валидации отключены) :

```
class ContactForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  public $id;
  public $user_id;
  //...
}
```

var_dump:

```
object(app\models\ContactForm)#214 (12) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["user_id"]=> int(4) ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> NULL ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

Таблицы: *user* и *contact form*

```
$this->createTable('user', [
  'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
  //...
], $tableOptions);
```

и

```
$this->createTable('{{%contact}}', [
  'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
  'user_id' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
  //...
], $tableOptions);


$this->createIndex(
  'idx-contact-user_id',
  'contact',
  'user_id'
);


$this->addForeignKey(
  'fk-contact-user_id',
  'contact',
  'user_id',
  'user',
  'id',
  'CASCADE'
);
```

При этом вручную через *phpMyAdmin* запись осуществляется.

В чем может быть причина проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В модели была ошибка, не нужно определять в public эти переменные:

```
 // public $id;
 // public $user_id;
```